# Unable to connect to Nexmo API from Azure

Tags: .net, azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, vonage

My application is hosted on the cloud (microsoft azure) , i am trying to verify the mobile number using https://api.nexmo.com/ni/basic/json?api_key=xxx&api_secret=xxxxxx&number=, everything was working normally, then suddenly i am now no longer able to connect to the api through azure, although i can connect to the api locally ,i am getting this error An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. I tried updating the TLS to V1.2 but i keep getting the same error.

here is my code:

```
string nexmoRes = Utilities.ReadGetHtmlPage("https://api.nexmo.com/ni/basic/json?api_key=xxxx&api_secret=xxx&number=" + InternationalMSISDN, "");

public static string ReadGetHtmlPage(string url, string str)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                Utilities.writeLogs(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), "url " + url);
                objRequest.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr;
                sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.WriteToText(ex);
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.WriteToText(ex);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code for making the API call. The TLS setting in the portal only affects incoming connections, not egress.

Comment: @evilSnobu i updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Tried it on App Service, works fine for me, make sure you target [.NET 4.7 in your web.config](https://github.com/snobu/tls-negotiations) or explicitly select TLS 1.2 in `ServicePointManager` since your remote only speaks TLS 1.2 —

```
$ curl -i --tlsv1.0 "https://api.nexmo.com/ni/basic/json"
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed


$ curl -i --tlsv1.1 "https://api.nexmo.com/ni/basic/json"
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed


$ curl -i --tlsv1.2 "https://api.nexmo.com/ni/basic/json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
...
{
  "status": 4,
  "status_message": "Invalid credentials"
}
```

```csharp
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
...
```

If you go this route be aware the scope of `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is your entire App Domain.

Targeting .NET 4.7 instead of tinkering with `ServicePointManager` will bring you here, a much better place to be in —

[image: TLS version matrix]

App Service with Windows workers runs on Windows Server 2016 —

[image: App Service OS]